# If a set $E$ differs from a measurable set by a set of measure zero, then $E$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $F$ is Lebesgue measurable and $m(E-F)=0$. I want to convince myself that $E$ is also measurable, which seems intuitively true.

Since $F$ and $E-F$ are measurable, by additivity we have $m(E\cup F)=m(E-F\cup F)=m(E-F)+m(F)=m(F)$

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What if $E$ is a not measurable subset of $\mathbb R$? Then $m(E-\mathbb R)=m(\varnothing)=0$, but we cannot conclude that $E$ is measurable. I think you must work with $E\Delta F$ in stead of $E-F$. If $m(E\Delta F)=0$ and one of the sets $E,F$ is Lebesgue measurable then it can be shown that also the other is Lebesgue measurable. This on base of the fact that $m$ is a *complete* measure.

Comment: So then we would have $m(E-F)+m(F-E)=0$ where $F$ is measurable, but where would one go from there?

Comment: The *completeness* of $m$ then tells us that the null-sets $E-F$ and $F-E$ are measurable.

Comment: What does completeness of $m$ mean?

Comment: A measure $m$ is complete if it has the following property: if $A$ is measurable with $m(A)=0$ then every subset of $A$ is measurable. It is well known that the Lebesgue measure is complete.

Comment: Does every subset of $A$ then also have measure $0$?

Comment: That would follow from monotonicity I think

Comment: Yes, that is correct.